# Why is spring-boot-dependencies in dependencyManagement?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, dependency-management

The Spring documentation [Using Spring Boot without the parent POM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html) shows that the dependency on `spring-boot-dependencies` is added to the `dependencyManagement` section. Is this really correct?

spring-boot-dependencies specifies version properties for all the dependencies. However, these properties are not available in the POM that uses `spring-boot-dependencies`. Presumably, this is because `spring-boot-dependencies` is in `dependencyManagement`.

spring-boot-dependencies only includes `dependencyManagement` and `pluginManagement`. So it seems possible to include `spring-boot-dependencies` as a dependency (not dependencyManagement) without adding unnecessary dependencies.

So why is `spring-boot-dependencies` to be included as `dependencyManagement`?

Comment: I asked this question because I wanted to use `${jersey.version}` from `spring-boot-dependencies`. Since then I saw in the documentation that properties are only available when using the spring starter POM as the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely correct. Please see [Using Spring Boot without the parent POM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)!

Comment: Verified. Putting the `spring-boot-dependencies` dependency into the dependencies` section result in an error.

Comment: The documentation for the latest release has been shifted to:https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/

Answer (score 8):

> So why is spring-boot-dependencies to be included as dependencyManagement?

Let's say you have a project named `projectA` and you add the `spring-boot-dependencies` to the `dependencyManagement` section in your `pom.xml`.

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.iovation.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  ...
</project>
```

If you notice closely, you will find that all the Spring Boot dependencies declared under the `dependencies` section don't need to specify the `version`. It derives the `version` from the version of `spring-boot-dependencies` specified in the `dependencyManagement` section.

#### Advantages of Dependency Management

- It centralizes dependency information by specifying the Spring Boot version at one place. It really helps during upgrade from one version to another.
- Subsequent declaration of Spring Boot dependencies just mentions the library name without any version. Especially helpful in multi-module projects
- It avoids mismatch of different versions of spring boot libraries in a project.
- No Conflicts.

Comment: In my case I need one more dependency that is not included in the spring boot dependencies. I hoped to "inherit" the version from the spring boot dependencies, rather than re-defining it explicitly, so that when spring boot is upgraded, I don't risk forgetting to update the additional dependency's version. Unfortunately properties are only available when inherited (but not via dependency management), and I need to inherit from my project tree.

Answer (score -1):

- First, let’s understand what dependency is. So when you are developing an application, you would probably need a number of libraries(normally jar files). It means that your application depends on these libraries. Hence the name dependency.
- Now you need a way to assemble all these libraries and manage them in a centralized fashion. This also means that these libraries would be made available at compile time or runtime when needed. This is what dependency management does.
- So the process of dependency management involves locating these dependencies and adding them to the classpath.
- Maven is a popular dependency management tool which will centralize all dependencies information.